# Get Connection string from DBContext for DB Migration in Azure Functions Net5.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-functions, connection-string, database-migration

I have a Azure function solution which is using EF. I'm injecting the DBContext in the startup.cs class.

**My project layout**

- Project>.**Function** (Startup.cs, Function classes ) - Set as startup project
- Project>.**Infrastructure** (Has the DBContext class, Generated DB table Models)

**appsettings.json**

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDbCon": "Server=xxxx..............."
  },
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
.....
    serviceCollection.AddDbContext<MySampleContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbCon"));
    });
...
}
```

**DBContext class (MySampleContext.cs)**

```
public partial class MySampleContext : DbContext
{
   private string connectionString;

   public MySampleContext()
   {

   }

   public MySampleContext(DbContextOptions<MySampleContext> options, IConfiguration   configuration) : base(options)
   {
        var sqlServerOptionsExtension = options.FindExtension<SqlServerOptionsExtension>();
        if (sqlServerOptionsExtension != null)
        {
            this.connectionString = sqlServerOptionsExtension.ConnectionString;
        }
   }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(this.connectionString);
        }
    }
 ...
}
```

When i run the function locally, the DBContext is injected as expected. The parameterised constructure is called and im able to get the connection string. All good

**BUT** when i try to run the following commands

```
dotnet ef migrations script --output .\Infrastructure\Migrations\migration_script.sql --startup-project .\Functions --project .\Infrastructure
```

or

```
 Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

from the PackageManager Console im getting error: **Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')**. This I know is because the default constructure is being used and the connecting string is null

```
   public MySampleContext()
   {

   }
```

When I hardcode the connection string all is Ok, but How do I get the connection string (using the default constructure) so I'm able to run EF commands above without hardcoding the connection string?

```
public MySampleContext()
{
    this.connectionString = "Server=........";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 parts here -

1. Getting connection string from settings (local.settings.json).
2. Setting up EF (code-first) with Azure Functions
3. Generating Migrations
4. Making it all work on Azure

**Part 1:** For connection string -

In your **local.settings.json** add the following -

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "MyDbCon": "your-connection-string-here",
}
```

Then in your startup code, use it like this -

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MySampleContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyDbCon"));
});
```

**Part 2**: Setting up EF with Azure Function -

This one requires a bit of setup if you're doing code first. The following steps are defined for EF Core, it should be the same for EF.

Add the following nugets -

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

**If** your data-access project is separate from the main project, then **add the Micrsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design nuget to the main project** as well.

Now create a file next to your "MySampleContext" calling it - **MySampleContextFactory** and add the following -

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

namespace MySampleProject.DataAccess
{
    public class MySampleContextFactory: IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MySampleContext>
    {
        public MySampleContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MySampleContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyDbCon"));

            return new MySampleContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

So your MySampleContext will now have a constructor like -

```
public MySampleContext(DbContextOptions<MySampleContext> options) : base(options)
{
    // add other required code here
}
```

**Part 3**: Generating Migrations

For this open your package manager console, add the connection string to the environment as a variable so the MySampleContextFactory can pick it up.

Ensure the data-access project is selected (if it isn't your main project)

In the package manager console, enter the following -

```
$env:MyDbCon="your-connection-string-here"
```

[image]

- Note: If you still get the connection string not found error, you'll
  need to restart visual studio and enter the above again.

Now you can continue with the normal EF migration commands in the package manager console (do select the data-access library/project)  -

```
add-migration InitialCreate
update-database
```

This is enough for it all to work locally. But few more steps are involved to make it work once its published.

**Part 4:** Making it all work in the cloud

To apply the migration to your Cloud SQL (e.g. SQL Database on Azure), you need to apply the "update-database" with your cloud-sql connection string. So you need to restart Visual Studio and enter the new connection string,

```
$env:MyDbCon="sql-db-cloud-conn-string"
update-database
```

**Finally**, for it to work on Azure Function once published, you need to add the MyDbCon to the application settings in the portal.

Go to your Function App in the portal and add the following & then click **SAVE** -

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you say is correct but it still didnt tell me how to get the connecting string popultaed (via the default constructor) when running the migration commands

Comment: Mate, you cannot do it like that in Azure Functions. You need to provide the connection string as an environment variable in the Package Manager Console. See PART 3 of my answer. You need to enter $env:MyDbConn="your-conn-string". and then run the migration commands.